# Set up an OpenVPN server inside VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, openvpn

My goal is to set up OpenVPN server on my PC as a guest in a virtual machine. 
I would like to use that OpenVPN server to join my home network from anywhere.
On my PC (host) machine (192.168.1.116/24)
I set a new vagrant box (OpenVPN server):

```
config.vm.define "node1" do |node1|
node1.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1904"
node1.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.88"
```

So my OpenVPN server sits on my home network with local IP 192.168.1.88. Here is the output from "ip a" command (eth0 is created default by VirtualBox):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:11:de:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 84383sec preferred_lft 84383sec
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d2:71:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.88/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I installed and configured OpenVPN server via command:

```
wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-install.sh && bash openvpn-install.sh
```

Script "openvpn-install.sh" needs from me the IPv4 address of the network interface you want OpenVPN listening to. My question is that what IP should put there? 192.168.1.88 or public IP from https://ipchicken.com/?

Comment: Looking at the script it appears you want to input `192.168.1.88` and then you will be asked for the public IP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I opened the generated ovpn file with my phone (connected to 4g), but it got timeout. Here is snippet from the client ovpn file: `client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote <public_ip> 1194 etc...`

Comment: My phone is trying to connect to my "public_ip" on port 1194, I also opened a port forwarding on my router for internal ip 192.168.1.155 (openvpn server) - for port 1194, but it doesn't help :/

Comment: Ok, I managed to connect from my phone (4G) to my OpenVPN server ... I can ping connected devices on my home network from my phone....but my phone doesn't have internet :/